# Large initial solutions to $x^3+y^3 = Nz^3$?

Tags: diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

Let $x,y,z$ be *non-zero integers*. Is it true that the *initial* or smallest solution (in terms of absolute value) to,

$$x^3+y^3 = Nz^3\tag1$$

for $N=94$ is,

$$15642626656646177^3 + (-15616184186396177)^3 = 94\cdot 590736058375050^3\,?$$

If not, then what is the largest *initial* solution for $N<100$? Or $N<200$?

**P.S.** Related posts are [$x^3+y^3 = 6z^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287983/), and [$x^3+y^3 = 22z^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190385/), and [$x^3+y^3 = 313^2z^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1613635/4781). See also [this paper](http://people.ucsc.edu/~sdasgup2/clay.pdf) by Dasgupta and Voight for more details (including the elliptic curve for eq.1).

Comment: This is the value given at https://oeis.org/A190356 but there's a warning there that it may not be the smallest solution for $N=94$.

Comment: See also Table 1.4 of Introduction to Modern Number Theory: Fundamental Problems, Ideas and Theories by Yu. I. Manin and Alexei A. Panchishkin.

Comment: But what you really want to see is Andrew Bremner, Positively prodigious powers or how Dudeney done it?, Math Mag 84 (2011) 120-125.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks! That OEIS link referred to [Hisanori Mishima's list](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~KC2H-MSM/ec/eca1/x3y3s.txt) with $N<1000$. The paper by Dasgupta does refer to the solution for $N=94$ as a (Mordell-Weil) generator (but of course there could be a smaller generator).

Comment: Can anyone help me find (with a computer search) nonzero integers $a,b,c,d,e,n$ such that
$$a^3-nb^3=c^3-nd^3=e^3$$
where $(a,b,e)$ and $(c,d,e)$ are pairwise coprime and $n^2\ne 1$

One solution set will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some insight courtesy of Achille Hui, I was able to answer my own question. It is well known (see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605182/)) that $x^3+y^3=N$ is birationally equivalent to the *elliptic curve* $u^3-432N^2=v^2$ using the transformation $x=\frac{36N+v}{6u}$, $y=\frac{36N-v}{6u}$.

In [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581702/finding-integer-solutions-to-y2-x37x9-using-wolframalpha?noredirect=1#comment3219621_1581702), Hui suggested the command,

> Q$<x>$ := PolynomialRing(Rationals()); E00 := EllipticCurve(x^3-432*94^2); Q00 := Generators(E00); Q00;

on the [Magma online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). We then find,

> (62511752209/2480625 : -15629405421521177/3906984375 : 1)

Substituting this onto the transformation, we get,

$$x = \frac{15642626656646177}{590736058375050}\\
y = \frac{-15616184186396177}{590736058375050}$$

thus Magma confirms the solution given in the original question is indeed the smallest.

**P.S.** Incidentally, the numerators nicely factor as,

$$15642626656646177-15616184186396177 =2^4\cdot 3^8\cdot5^6 \cdot 7^3\cdot47$$