# Finding integer solutions to $y^2=x^3+7x+9$ using WolframAlpha

Tags: numerical-methods, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, computer-algebra-systems

I am an unconditional admirer of WolframAlpha and for this reason I want to let the people of this error (or is it really the fault of mine?). If I'm not mistaken, I would be very happy to contribute, communicating this default calculation, to this extraordinary and beneficial website.

I was watching something on the cubic curve 
$$y^2=x^3+7x+9$$
More precisely I was interested in integer points $(x, y)$ with both coordinates being prime numbers. I thought having in hand the point $ (5,\pm 13) $ but, consulting WolphramAlpha, his answer gives only the two points $(-1,\pm 1)$ and $(0,\pm 3)$

Maybe I need to rest a bit ...

[image]

Comment: $5^{2} \ne 13^{3} + 7(13) + 9$.. 

Have a rest.

Comment: Perhaps OP meant (5,13)

Comment: Absolutely! it is $(5,\pm13)$

Comment: Thank you, @pjs36 for the tag of (computer-algebra-systems) I did not know.

Comment: Sure! I'm just trying to get the question visibility; I like it. I have no idea how to get WolframAlpha to find integer points, and I'm interested in finding out. The more I think about it, it might help to attach a concrete question, like "Can I use WolframAlpha to find integer points on an elliptic curve?" or something. I think that's what you're asking, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is certainly due to excellent programming and powerful computer. The elliptic curves are fascinating but at all times they ask very hard calculations. And their open problems are extremely difficult (there are waiting for a proof the heavenly  Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture and that the rank is not bounded (or find a bound tough i feel rather not bounded)

Comment: For stuff on elliptic curves, the [online Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) is a much better choice than wolfram alpha. Throwing following commands
`Q<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals());}
E00  := EllipticCurve(x^3+7*x+9);
Q00  := IntegralPoints(E00);
Q00;`
to the online calculator, one get
$(x,y) = (-1,\pm 1), (0, \pm 3), (5, \pm 13), (17, \pm 71), (27,\pm 141)$.

Comment: Extremely interesting: the curve has two points both with the two prime-coordinates !. Thank for the Magma calculator but the WolframAlpha will be always interesting.

Comment: @achillehui: May I know what is the ***Magma*** command  to find an initial rational point (not necessarily integral) on $x^3+7x+9 = y^2$?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I'm not that familiar with Magma but you can use `Generators(E00)` to get the generators.

Comment: @achillehui: Thanks. I'm trying to answer [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613119/a-diophantine-equation-with-only-titanic-solutions). It can be reduced to solving $p^3+q^3 = 313^2$, hence the elliptic curve $w^3-432\cdot313^4 = t^2$. Using your _IntegralPoints_ command, Magma said there is, but it seems too big to print it out. Same with the _Generators_ thingie. :( Do you know how to find a rational point on that elliptic curve?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I don't. Actually, I tried using magma a few hours ago for the same EC and have essentially same problem as you.

Comment: @achillehui: Ok, thanks though.

Comment: I finally think that Wolfram was not wrong but gave answers ranging over a fixed interval (more so, I think it offers the possibility of extending its considered range)

Answer (score 1):

I believe wolfram is right, $$(-13)^3+7(-13)+9=-2279 \neq 5^2$$ and similarly $$13^3+7(13)+9=2297  \neq 5^2$$ and $\sqrt{2297} \notin \mathbb Z$

EDIT: Switching $x$ and $y$ it seems that $5^3+7(5)+9=13^2$, so yes you're correct!

Comment: OK, they mixed up $x$ and $y$. But $5^3 + 7 \cdot 5 + 9 = 169$

Comment: Yes you're correct thank you!

Comment: Sorry, dear friend, it was the point $(5,\pm13)$. I really need a rest.