# Sum of two cubes transformed to elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Given $x^3+y^3=N$, we can perform some substitutions to obtain an elliptic curve $u^3-432N^2=v^2$, as given [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100125133830/http://maths.paisley.ac.uk/allanm/ecrnt/twocubes/twocubes.htm), which are $x=\frac{36N+v}{6u}$, $y=\frac{36N-v}{6u}$. Here's the details:
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{36N+v}{6u}\right)^3+\left(\frac{36N-v}{6u}\right)^3 &=N \\
u^3-432N^2 &=v^2\end{align*}

What's the inspiration for these substitutions? I see why linear substitutions won't work so perhaps I should have tried a simple rational substitution.

Comment: I don't see how those substitutions give you the required form. I see nothing replacing the $x$ terms in any of the substitutions.

Comment: Yikes! I probably shouldn't have glazed over the last step. The other substitution mentioned in the webpage seems to work. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I corrected your typos. You can check it with this [WA link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5B%28%2836n+%2B+v%29%2F%286u%29%29%5E3%2B%28%2836n+-+v%29%2F%286u%29%29%5E3+-+n%5D). (The equation $u^3-432N^2=v^2$ is well-known.)