# When does $(a+b\sqrt n)^3+(a-b\sqrt n)^3=c^3$ have integer solutions $(a,b,c,n)$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, computational-mathematics

From this post [*Where Fermat's Last Theorem fails*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713770/where-fermats-last-theorem-fails), we find the nice,

$$(18+17\sqrt2)^3+(18-17\sqrt2)^3=42^3$$

Using this initial solution, an infinite more can be generated using P. Tait's identity,

$$\big(x(y^3 + z^3)\big)^3 + \big(y(-x^3 - z^3)\big)^3  = \big(z(x^3 - y^3)\big)^3$$

which is true if $x^3+y^3=z^3.\,$ For example, the first leads to a second,

$$(707472 + 276119 \sqrt{2})^3 + (707472 - 276119 \sqrt{2})^3 = 1106700^3$$

and so on infinitely. But it is also the case that,

$$(2+\sqrt{-2})^3+(2-\sqrt{-2})^3=(-2)^3$$
$$(121+23\sqrt{-11})^3+(121-23\sqrt{-11})^3=(-88)^3$$

all of which are *unique factorization domains* UFD ${\bf Q}(\sqrt n)$. So at first I thought it was peculiar to UFDs, but expanding,

$$(a+b\sqrt n)^3+(a-b\sqrt n)^3=c^3$$

we get the simpler,

$$2 a^3 + 6 a b^2 n = c^3\tag{eq.1}$$

After I tested various $n$, it didn't seem to be limited to UFDs. For example,

$$(256+11\sqrt{-41})^3+(256-11\sqrt{-41})^3=296^3$$

**Question**: Can $2 a^3 + 6 a b^2 n = c^3$ (labeled as eq.1) be turned into an elliptic curve similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605182/sum-of-two-cubes-transformed-to-elliptic-curve) so we can easily find $n$ for which eq.1 is solvable? If not, what are the $-100 < n < 100$ such that $(1)$ has a solution? (Is it in the OEIS?)

**P.S.** We avoid square $n$, since by FLT $x^3+y^3=z^3$, it just yields trivial solutions $xyz = 0$. Or if $n=-3m^2$, then $(a,b,c) = (3m,\,1,\,0)$  so we avoid $abc =0$ as well.

Comment: In your **Question**, what do you mean by 'find $n$'? Do you mean to find $n$ for which $x^3+y^3=z^3$ has a solution in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$? Or do you require that $z\in\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Servaes Yes, but for now we focus on the form $(a+b\sqrt{n})^3+(a-b\sqrt{n})^3 = c^3$ where c is a non-zero integer.  **P.S.** The more general form of course is $(a+b\sqrt{n})^3+(c+d\sqrt{n})^3 = (e+f\sqrt{n})^3$ where $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ are all non-zero, but I haven't found an example of that yet.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III,                                           
(a+bm)^k+(a-bm)^k = (c+dm)^k+(c-dm)^k, for k=3 has solution, 
(a,b,c,d)=(2,3,5,1) & m=(3)^(1/2) and for k=5, a=(1280)^(1/2),
b=(255)^(1/2),c=(5)^(1/2),d=(4085)^(1/2) & m=1

Comment: @David The equation $a^k+b^k = c^k+d^k$ can be solved in quadratic integers up to $k=11$ with the FLT-like restriction $abcd \neq 0$. With that restriction, it is unknown if it can be brought higher for $k > 11$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821037/the-diophantine-a11-b11-c11-d11-s-for-eisenstein-integers) for more details.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III. The reason I suggested the form, (a^k+b^k)=(c^k+d^k), is because I noticed in your comment that you are looking for a solution to equation,[(a+sqrt{bn})^3+(c+sqrt{dn})^3 = (e+sqrt{fn})^3]. This equation is asymetrical in the sence that the (LHS) has two terms & the (RHS) has only one term. Hence it could be difficult to find numerical solutions to it. Regarding degree thirteen for my proposed equation do read my comment for the (MSE) question with the link shown here.   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elliptic curve version.

$2a^3+6ab^2n = c^3$ can be reduced to $v^2 = -12nx^4+6nx$ with $x=a/c,y=b/c, v=6nxy$.

Furthermore, we can tranform $v^2 = -12nx^4+6nx$ to $Y^2 = X^3-432n^3$ with $X=6n/x,Y=6nv/x^2$.

The solutions are derived from one of the generators, so it may not be the smallest.

```
           (n,a,b,c)
           (-197, 425716141676, 17561345519, -95739315770)
           (-195, 2028, 131, -2886)
           (-194, 306808280101845674, 10558172571357337, 261831462443345254)
           (-191, 19652, 821, -986)
           (-186, 162, 41, -666)
           (-185, 23715170572, 805056269, 21263774126)
           (-182, 152210180652894, 7057684092887, -107041044260514)
           (-179, 256, 53, -904)
           (-177, 1500, 5264447, -3534330)
           (-174, 6, 1, -18)
           (-173, 4000000, 1838360791, -2411975800)
           (-170, 144, 5, 132)
           (-167, 1, 1, -10)
           (-161, 4442376652, 236037857, -3994761778)
           (-159, 1029, 43, 714)
           (-158, 304423498, 2560955153, -12369700078)
           (-155, 25, 1, 20)
           (-149, 79433915648, 3751090247, 14738891176)
           (-146, 10658, 19847, -154322)
           (-143, 169, 5, 182)
           (-141, 607836, 6037, 755022)
           (-137, 5756278756, 1896400265, -25527545782)
           (-134, 2569424405062, 1495926864335, -16617711752314)
           (-131, 1, 107, -208)
           (-129, 12, 1, -18)
           (-123, 96, 5, -12)
           (-122, 7442, 389, -122)
           (-119, 49, 31, -322)
           (-114, 775235226, 52094663, -797509914)
           (-113, 63253004, 8638589, -139147874)
           (-110, 18, 1, -6)
           (-109, 4500, 253, -1830)
           (-107, 243, 29, -468)
           (-106, 18, 1, 6)
           (-105, 2888844, 141143, 2286942)
           (-101, 907924000, 52423201, -247766140)
           (-95, 361, 235, -2242)
           (-89, 36, 1, 42)
           (-87, 81, 5, 18)
           (-86, 16, 1, -4)
           (-83, 9, 5, -48)
           (-78, 1014, 58735, -117858)
           (-77, 67228, 83253539, -59932978)
           (-74, 407625226, 30897005, -334158322)
           (-71, 1, 5, -22)
           (-69, 15972, 1255, -13134)
           (-65, 676, 33581, -66742)
           (-62, 16, 5, -52)
           (-59, 9, 1, -12)
           (-53, 2304, 13609, -51384)
           (-51, 12, 1, -6)
           (-47, 4, 1, -10)
           (-42, 294, 2395, -7518)
           (-41, 256, 11, 296)
           (-38, 6498, 7057, -41838)
           (-35, 49, 5, -28)
           (-33, 12, 25, -114)
           (-31, 9, 1, -6)
           (-29, 288, 191, -1212)
           (-26, 3042, 307, 2262)
           (-23, 9, 1, 6)
           (-17, 4, 29, -70)
           (-15, 3, 1, -6)
           (-14, 98, 31, -182)
           (-11, 1, 1, -4)
           (-6, 6, 1, 6)
           (-5, 4, 1, 2)
           (-2, 2, 1, -2)
           (2, 18, 17, 42)
           (5, 9, 1, 12)
           (6, 6, 5, 18)
           (11, 246924, 168275, 789222)
           (14, 5058568998, 13722993145, 43138907994)
           (15, 12, 43, 126)
           (17, 36, 127, 390)
           (23, 377606781684, 274693407295, 1592635446402)
           (26, 10494278917902, 202621693481065, 406588108522206)
           (29, 243, 7295, 13104)
           (33, 12, 1, 18)
           (35, 284784377187481164, 154212287927062829, 1136627710868147862)
           (38, 2224710090824741532242298, 682526736456078049630579, 6368669335721179285647342)
           (41, 288, 40955, 49164)
           (42, 645918, 34007, 899262)
           (43, 4, 11, 50)
           (47, 71734416291045108, 2220116835128461, 94277936072724450)
           (51, 514500, 413221, 3005730)
           (53, 15166431, 10329073, 80493504)
           (58, 1682, 25, 2146)
           (59, 7358173787172289500, 8608159082661727764757, 5779158750471360655230)
           (62, 24617358, 1598549, 37619010)
           (65, 308172852, 30203753, 551979246)
           (69, 81, 55, 468)
           (71, 2203793333881819021004544, 9853319396397693506345, 2780540935484837082868632)
           (74, 5723994783817163598634351926, 1393441383372024857043537865, 17445840971557474688254138278)
           (77, 4261646277, 55593553, 5438792268)
           (78, 667722042, 298862351, 3054806118)
           (82, 2, 1, 10)
           (83, 101401546779607829751759181824, 78095516271323295246676139023, 676839307868352923167913503536)
           (85, 1, 1, 8)
           (86, 11054250, 7107523, 66255630)
           (87, 2670540192, 154541347, 4148286948)
           (89, 4500, 105999947, 30000030)
           (93, 3, 1, 12)
           (101, 569277036000, 6183969793, 725692439940)
           (105, 588, 565, 4914)
           (106, 128, 5, 184)
           (109, 4, 1, 14)
           (110, 2558788532262, 246175379371, 5140697537226)
           (113, 53757763452, 16747406609, 219208021578)
           (114, 2890815729966, 327923088175, 6390219852198)
           (119, 85778248500, 1543310322733, 5264153630610)
           (123, 38901504, 2108117, 62601336)
           (134, 69744445649988575971907142, 419714537773835540334275214965, 214564515347932269394392052626)
           (137, 4775436, 972389, 15780114)
           (141, 1500, 1, 1890)
           (142, 18, 1, 30)
           (149, 7716375, 414647, 12815880)
           (155, 18456894399119616, 25901779522726321, 225904518368817288)
           (158, 177521844998411170826779098, 1805092471425063874803121, 227259216648420795612185622)
           (159, 203504954086656, 133367294253005, 1513952552186568)
           (161, 8666532, 244085, 12165846)
           (170, 81927315839221632, 3202809636185995, 125083122754631496)
           (173, 14145645792229575872157, 705144424515109688777, 23490393278718337138440)
           (177, 324, 23, 630)
           (185, 493138113204901915743156, 38127741324790671795497, 1011726091067655550214238)
           (186, 105456, 1955, 140868)
           (191, 293286031033541406772830187500, 13454207475992182129546755850903, 39330626629787271278291036795550)
           (195, 34304062637364, 189340166991769, 1128964881768282)
           (197, 15991018092, 1748033461, 40398858570)
```

Comment: +1 Great! I knew there had to be an elliptic curve. How remarkable that the elliptic curve for $x^3+y^3 = N$ as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605182/sum-of-two-cubes-transformed-to-elliptic-curve) and for this post are so similar, $$u^3-432N^2 = v^2$$ $$X^3-432n^3 = Y^2$$

Comment: Tomita, looking at your solutions, at first I thought $\pm n$ would _both_ have solutions. However, since the elliptic curve is $X^3-2(6n)^3 = y^2$, then there is a qualitative difference between positive and negative cases. For example, I find n =+(43, 58, 82, 85, 93, 142) has no negative counterpart. Likewise, I find n = -(31, 95, 107, 122, 129, 131, 143, 146, 167, 174, 179, 182, 194) has no positive counterpart. Just for info.

Comment: For $n=(-19,-43,-67,-163)$, Magma says that elliptic curve has rank $0$ and has no integer points.

Comment: I have a non-monic quartic polynomial to be made a square $(ax^2+bx+c)(x+1)x = y^2$. What is the Magma command to solve this in the rationals where $x\neq-1$ and $x\neq0$? For example, $219(3x^2+3x+1)(x+1)x = y^2$. Any rational solution?

Comment: @Tito,First, transform quartic to elliptic curve $E.$ 
Next,  use Magma command Generators($E$) and Rank($E$).
$219(3x^2+3x+1)(x+1)x = y^2$ can be transformed to $Y^2=X^3+31974X -2723119.$
E := EllipticCurve([0, 0, 0, 31974, -2723119]);
SetClassGroupBounds("GRH");
Rank(E);
Generators(E);

Magma says $E$ has rank $0$ and has only solution $(X,Y)=(73,0).$
Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591990/birational-equivalence-of-diophantine-equations-and-elliptic-curves/1592599#1592599) how to transform quartic to elliptic curve.

Comment: The linked post was actually edited by me. I always have trouble when the leading or ending coefficient is a non-square. So this is Case 2. In summary, I assume the only rational $x$ of $219(3x^2+3x+1)(x+1)x=y^2$ is $x = -1$ and $x = 0$?

Comment: Extrapolating from your cubic, I guess that the quartic $3d(3x^2+3x+1)(x+1)x = y^2$ can be transformed to the cubic $X^3+6d^2 X-7d^3 = Y^2$. I tested it on primes $d = p^2+3q^2$ and of primes $d\leq163$, only two failed, namely $d=73,97$. I thought they'd all pass. This has to do with $x^3+y^3+z^3 = t^3$. I'll post a new question soon.

Comment: @Tito, Yes, I think the quartic $3d(3x^2+3x+1)(x+1)x=y^2$ can be transformed to the cubic $X^3+6d^2X−7d^3=Y^2.$

Comment: I have made the question. Kindly check out this [new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4847666/on-the-elliptic-curve-x3-6-cdot-1632-x-7-cdot-1633-y2-and-others).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this is the answer you want.

Search results for $2a^3+6ab^2n = c^3$ where $-100<n<100$ and $(a,b)<1000$.

$n$ is squarefree.

```
           (n,a,b,c)
           (-95, 361, 235, -2242)
           (-89, 36, 1, 42)
           (-87, 81, 5, 18)
           (-86, 16, 1, -4)
           (-83, 9, 5, -48)
           (-71, 1, 5, -22)
           (-62, 16, 5, -52)
           (-59, 9, 1, -12)
           (-51, 12, 1, -6)
           (-47, 4, 1, -10)
           (-41, 256, 11, 296)
           (-35, 49, 5, -28)
           (-33, 12, 25, -114)
           (-31, 9, 1, -6)
           (-29, 288, 191, -1212)
           (-23, 9, 1, 6)
           (-17, 4, 29, -70)
           (-15, 3, 1, -6)
           (-14, 98, 31, -182)
           (-11, 1, 1, -4)
           (-6, 6, 1, 6)
           (-5, 4, 1, 2)
           (-2, 2, 1, -2)
           (1, 1, 1, 2)
           (2, 18, 17, 42)
           (5, 9, 1, 12)
           (6, 6, 5, 18)
           (15, 12, 43, 126)
           (17, 36, 127, 390)
           (33, 12, 1, 18)
           (43, 4, 11, 50)
           (58, 16, 283, 764)
           (69, 81, 55, 468)
           (82, 2, 1, 10)
           (85, 1, 1, 8)
           (93, 3, 1, 12)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! The sequence (2,5,6,11,14,15,17,23) has only one hit in OEIS but the next term is 26, and it doesn't seem to be related to $x^3+y^3 = z^3$. It is interesting that the $a$-variable are all of form $u^2,\,2v^2,\,3w^2$. Furthermore, abs(primes) of the form $n=-(6m-1)$ are represented, except $n=-53$. Can you extend the table to $-200<n<200$? (Converting $2a^3+6ab^2n=c^3$ to an _elliptic curve_ would be ideal, since even if $n=-53$ has large solutions, then the online _Magma_ calculator can find it.)

Comment: @Tito, Sure!  I'll try it.

Comment: You may like [this new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4852495/still-more-elliptic-curves-for-a4b4c4-d4) about elliptic curves and $a^4+b^4+c^4 =d^4$.